# How to organize the auxiliare and pdf output files in folders with WinEdt 10.3?

Tags: winedt

I would like to organize the auxiliary and pdf output files in folders such as [in this video](https://youtu.be/Sa_fUc_RKAk), but I don't know as to do this in WinEdt (version 10.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer as a set rhetorical question
**1) why is such advice not easily available over the past 3 decades ?

A) perhaps it is not a good idea**

**WinEdt is a special case that self configures itself in a way it understands**

see manual 2.5 TEX AUX Output Folder **(%P\TeXAux)**
*"For the more discerning, this feature can be further conﬁgured in the TeX Options page of Execution Modes. As always, clicking on Help in that dialog will explain the details."*

**2) Why would it not work to make my own changes as per you tube**

A) because a pdf in one folder cannot easily sync with a TeX in another folder
so lets remove the synctex directive

B) leaving breaches in security setting permanently open is not advisable
so lets remove both -shell-escape & -enable-write18 directives

c) indexing and citing/biblio auxiliaries generally need to be in the same folder as the main.tex and certainly do not restructure well when within sibling subfolders
so lets remove the aux directive

D) setting graphics path via parent rarely works especially when you do need to run some image manipulation via shell-escape except on some rare occasions when someone tries to make a point that it works for them.
So lets remove \graphics...../imagens/

**What are we left with**

Answer WinEdt command is same as it always was/should be

**pdfTeXify**